# Why does pandas drop group index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Consider the following two examples using the test dataframe:

```
df_temp = {
   'id': [0,0,0,1,1,1],
   'time' : [1,2,3,1,2,3],
   'values': [3,6,1,4,0,-1]
}
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df_temp)
df_temp = df_temp.set_index('time')
```

Case 1:

```
df_temp.groupby('id')[['values']].apply(lambda _df: _df)
```

Case 2:

```
df_temp.groupby('id')[['values']].apply(lambda _df: _df[:-1])
```

In case 1, the output drops the groupby index, i.e., `id=0,1`, while in case 2, the output keeps the groupby index and prepends it in front forming a multi-index `(id, time)`. Why is this? And how should I modify the first case so that it also keeps the groupby index without cutting out the last row of each group as in case 2?

Comment: There's a parameter that seems to be relevant, [`group_keys`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#control-grouped-column-s-placement-with-group-keys), though I can't get `group_keys=True` to do anything different on Pandas 1.4.4 and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Found it: [`group_keys=True` behaviour changed in 1.5.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#using-group-keys-with-transformers-in-groupby-apply)

Comment: @wjandrea Thx! But do you know of any work arounds for previous versions of pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Let me attempt to give an answer to your second question. **If you are sure that your `apply` yields a like-indexed dataframe as the original dataframe**, then a workaround is to reindex using multiindex.

```
out = df_temp.groupby('id')[['values']].apply(lambda _df: _df)
out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df_temp['id'], df_temp.index])
```

Note it doesn't work if your apply doesn't result in the same index.